# Get element title inside td of selected row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a table in ASP.NET MVC, and I want when user click on a row and select item in my "select" tag, i can get the title of the item in "select" tag. Here's my table body and what I've tried:

```
<tbody>
            <tr class="record-template" style="display:none">

                <td>
                    <select class="cboMaPT form-control" name="MA_PT">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ListPhuTung)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Value"> @item.Text </option>
                        }
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <select  class="cboMaTienCong form-control" name="MA_TIENCONG" onchange="MyFunc()" >
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ListTienCong)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.MA_TIENCONG" title="@item.SOTIEN" > @item.MA_TIENCONG </option>
                        }
                    </select>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input  type="text" class="txtSoluong form-control" name="SOLUONG" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txtDonGia form-control" name="DONGIA" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txtTienCong form-control" name="TIENCONG" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class=" txtThanhTien form-control" name="THANHTIEN" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txtBaoHanh form-control" name="THOIHAN_BAOHANH" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

My javascript function to catch onchange event but it didn't work:

```
        function MyFunc()
    {

        alert($('#product-table').closest('tr').find(".cboMaTienCong").children("option").filter(":selected").attr("title"))

    }
```

Comment: which event you want to get the title click or selecting option?

Comment: i use onchange event in this: onchange="MyFunc()" inline 12

Comment: then use this context like $('option:selected',this).attr('title')

Comment: however, my table can have more than one row so how can I get the row user selects

Comment: There is no `#product-table` element in the posted code?

Comment: oops, sorry that's my mistake. the #product-table is the id of my table